# is it possible to embed an interactive IPython Notebook in my website/blog?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Suppose I've created my *wonderful* IPython notebook (that is, a .ipynb file).
Now, is it possible to make it available for users of my website/blog?

With "available" I mean the following: they arrive to my website, find the notebook and immediately start to play with it (run code, display plots, change parameters etc etc)... But, **without need the need to install anything on their local machine.**

I already know the existence of Jupyther, that make it possible to share notebooks. But, [as in this example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter1_Introduction/Chapter1.ipynb), what the user would find is a simple web page, and in order to run the code he would have to download the .ipynb --> save it in local machine ---> open it with a pre-installed IPython interpreter.
This is something I would like to avoid.

Hope I was clear.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Gabriele

Answer (score 4):

You can use [tmpnb](https://github.com/jupyter/tmpnb), which provides temporary notebook servers that get discarded after a while. If you want to have a different UI that better fits into a blog post, have a look at [thebe](https://github.com/oreillymedia/thebe).